# facing the issue with SELECT DML changes in oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle10g

Please help me to write query in oracle  .

I want to retrieve the records once update the some records, that should be Done in single transaction. i need in oracle.

I have used earlier  DB2 , like the below query .

`SELECT * FROM FINAL TABLE(update query ).`

What Happens with the above query is update some records based on some condition and will return same list of results, is it possible with Oracle.

Comment: can you elaborate `some`

Answer (score 0):

> update some records based on some condition and will return same list of results, is it possible with Oracle.

Oracle doesn't automatically maintain any track of the rows which were affected by **DML** statement. You need to have some mechanism implemented. You could write a **trigger** to maintain the history of the DML changes.

For example,

```
CREATE 
OR 
replace TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER 
UPDATE 
ON table_name FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF( Updating( 'COLUMN1' ) ) THEN 
INSERT INTO log_table 
            ( 
                        column_name, 
                        column_value 
            ) 
            VALUES 
            ( 
                        'COLUMN1', 
                        :new.column1 
            ); 

END IF; 
IF( Updating( 'COLUMN2' ) ) THEN 
  INSERT INTO log_table 
              ( 
                          column_name, 
                          column_value 
              ) 
              VALUES 
              ( 
                          'COLUMN2', 
                          :new.column2 
              ); 

END IF;
END;
```

Or you could enable **Auditing**.

If you are doing the DML in **PL/SQL**, you could use the **returning_clause** to get the rows which are affected by the DML.

For example,

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF t1.id%TYPE;
  l_tab t_tab;
BEGIN
  UPDATE t1
  SET    description = description
  RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab;

  FOR i IN l_tab.first .. l_tab.last LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('UPDATE ID=' || l_tab(i));
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
/
UPDATE ID=1
UPDATE ID=2
UPDATE ID=3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Read this [article](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause.php).